# PhpStorm live template expression to convert current variable

Tags: php, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide, live-templates

So we can use expressions to transform other variables in live templates.
For example:

[image: Working example with two variables while second one references the first one]

**Is it possible to apply `snakeCase` to `NAME` directly?** So whatever I type, gets converted into snake case? Desired result:

[image: Example with expected behaviour, having just one variable]

Tried `snakeCase(NAME)`, `snakeCase(String)` and `snakeCase()`. None seemed to work. Maybe someone had it figured out?

Comment: Show you live template / how you plan to use it. As Lena said, you may simply use another variable that will hold that value.

Comment: Well in this case I wanted to enforce snake_case for test method name, no matter how I type it in. Was just wondering if it's possible. Anyway, String Manipulation plugin will do the job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not possible - you can't pass a variable to itself, it has to be either another live template variable (defined before) or some known value calculated based on clipboard content (`snakeCase(clipboard())`), file name (`snakeCase(fileName())`), name got from completion, etc.

If you like to change names of existing variables, you can try [String Manipulation](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/2162-string-manipulation)  plugin, for example